# How we can compute the "principal factors" in a quadratic number field?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Let K be a quadratic number field with discriminant D. It's well known that a principal factor of K exists if and only if the fundamental unit of K has norm +1. Also I know that a principal factor of K, say t, is a divisor of D. But it's a question for me:" how I can find an explicit method to find of form of t"??

Comment: Maybe you could remind us what a "principal factor" is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, of Course!

Comment: @GerryMyerson A principal factor in K=Q(√m), is an integral principal ideal
of K which is composed entirely of ramified primes but is not generated by 1
or m^(1/2).

Comment: Thanks. But, you know which primes ramify in a quadratic field, right? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137449/basic-arithmetic-behind-ramification-in-quadratic-number-fields or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376590/vague-definitions-of-ramified-split-and-inert-in-a-quadratic-field

Comment: You can easily compute them from the fundamental unit. If no unit is known, check which ramified ideals are principal one by one. But this might tirn out to be difficult without knowing the unit group.